# Access third-party app functions with Google Assistant

Tags: android, node.js, integration, actions-on-google

I've created an app that counts the time you've spent on customers projects. I would now like to integrate this in Google Assistant, so when you say "Talk to MyTimeApp" and then say "Start counting time on Project A", the app should start the stopwatch.

So far this should be possible with Intents for Google Assistant and API.ai. But how can I manage to check which user is using my app (so who is logged in), in order to only access his account and his connected projects? In all the tutorial videos from Google, they provide only non-user-specific examples.

I've read about the possibility to provide also a login function. Can I therefore use my own registration-service or do I need to use the Google-Account? Or is there a way to access the installed TimeApp, where the user is already signed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Actions on Google system, which is how you build Actions for the Assistant, gives you a few options for authentication depending on exactly what your needs are.

First, if you're assuming they will be doing this on their phones that already has the app installed, then you can see if [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) will meet your need when they are available.

If you are looking to do this as a conversational Action that does not require the mobile app, and you already have an existing authentication system, then you would use [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) to link their Assistant account to the account that you have for them. This typically requires an OAuth2 server.

You can, if you wish, simplify this if your account is linked to their Google Account, in which case you'll be able to use [Google Sign-In for the Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) to handle the sign-in on all Assistant platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have to go with App Actions then.